# Running NSTimer on a thread

Tags: iphone, nstimer, nsthread, runloop

I am trying to run a NSTimer on a thread using iPhone SDK 3.0. I think I am doing everything correctly (new runloop etc.). If I call [timer invalidate] on viewDidDissappear though I get this error:

> bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x3986d60: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
>   Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    NSThread* timerThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(timerStart) object:nil]; //Create a new thread
    [timerThread start]; //start the thread
}

-(void)timerStart
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    //Fire timer every second to updated countdown and date/time
    timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(method) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];
    [runLoop run];
    [pool release];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [timer invalidate];
}
```

When I remove the line invalidating the timer everything works fine. Am I not supposed to invalidate it or am I making some other mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
[timer performSelector:@selector(invalidate) onThread:timerThread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

instead. You will have to make *timerThread* an ivar of your view controller.

Answer (score 2):

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSThread* timerThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(timerStart) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
    [timerThread start]; 
    }

    -(void)timerStart
    {
   @autoreleasePool{
    NSRunLoop *TimerRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [NSTimer scheduleTimerWithInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(methodName:) userInfo:nil repeat:YES];
    [TimerRunLoop run];
    }

    - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have done some UI work in "`method`".

```
 timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(method) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];
```

From the log, it seems you have done UI updating work it in "Timer" thread in "method".

you can use block to dispatch work on main thread or `performSeletorOnMainThread` for doing "method"