# NSTimer stops when we click on ScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my app am using UIScrollView which is having UIImageView(20) to add images iused the     **- (void)populateScrollView** method.

```
    - (void)populateScrollView
{
TonifyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TonifyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
double x1 = 0, y1 = 3;
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];            
NSMutableArray *getEffectsImageData = [ud objectForKey:@"getimageeffects"];
imageViewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[getEffectsImageData count]];
for(int i = 0; i < [getEffectsImageData count]; i++)
{ 
    NSString *sfxUrlFileName = [ [getEffectsImageData objectAtIndex:i] lastPathComponent];
    NSLog(@"sfxUrlFileName: %@", sfxUrlFileName);
    NSData *imageData = [appDelegate readSongDataFromDocsDirectory:sfxUrlFileName];
     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    UIImageView *anImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
    CGRect imageFrame = anImageView.frame;
    imageFrame.origin.x = x1;
    imageFrame.origin.y = y1;
    anImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x1, y1, 45, 41);
    anImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [scrollView addSubview:anImageView];
    x1 += anImageView.frame.size.width + 3;
    if (anImageView && [anImageView isMemberOfClass: [UIImageView class]]) 
        [imageViewsArray addObject: anImageView];
}

NSLog(@"imageViewsArray:%@",imageViewsArray);
}
```

And to recognize touch in UIScrollView i used

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Meanwhile am running song by using NSTimer which is like

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeinterval target:self selector:@selector(**updatplayer**) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

in **updatePlayer** method am doing task as follows

```
- (void)updatplayer
{
TonifyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TonifyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

if (mThresholdVal<mMainLoopLength) 
{
    mThresholdVal+=0.5; 
}
else
{
    mThresholdVal = 0.0;
}

if (divimageView)
{
    [divimageView removeFromSuperview];
}
if ([self isHeadsetPluggedIn]==NO) {
    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);

}
else
{
    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride); 
}
NSString *cu=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.f",audioPlayer.currentTime];
NSString *du=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.f",audioPlayer.duration];

NSLog(@"LOOP cu Duration = %@",cu);
NSLog(@"LOOP du = %@",du);

int curenttime=(int)[cu intValue];
NSLog(@"LOOP current Duration = %2.f",audioPlayer.duration);
if(curenttime==0)
{
    [audioPlayer play];

    x=20;
}

mixdata = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
{
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    activityIndicator.hidden = YES;

    [divimageView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, 87, 12, 144)];
    [self.view addSubview:divimageView];  

    x=x+1;

    if ((x>19 && x< 480) && appDelegate.songURL != NULL) {
         [avplayer play];
            NSLog(@"mixdata:%@", mixdata);

    }
    else if((x>19 && x< 480) &&  (appDelegate.songIntroUrl || appDelegate.songMidUrl || appDelegate.songChorusUrl) )
    {
        [audioPlayer play];
    }
if (x==xCord && yCord<235)
{
    [audioPlayer1 play];
}
if (x==recXcord) 
{
    recaudioPlayer.volume = 10.0;
    [recaudioPlayer play];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    activityIndicator.hidden = YES;

}

   if(appDelegate.xCordArray!=NULL && [appDelegate.tagArray count]>0)
   {

       for(int i = 0; i<[appDelegate.xCordArray count];i++)
       {
            if (i ==  0){
            NSLog(@"sfxCount in i==0......%d",sfxCount);
            NSLog(@"[appDelegate.xCordArray count] in i==0......%d",[appDelegate.xCordArray count]);
            NSLog(@"[appDelegate.mMixedSFXTrack2Array count] in i==0......%d",[appDelegate.mMixedSFXTrack2Array count]);

               if (sfxCount-1 !=  [appDelegate.xCordArray count])
               {
                   if ([appDelegate.xCordArray count] > [appDelegate.mMixedSFXTrack2Array count] )
                   {
                   mShouldBufferUpdate = TRUE;
                   sfxCount  = [appDelegate.xCordArray count];
                }
               }
           }

           if (x==[[appDelegate.xCordArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue] && appDelegate.imgDragXCodr<480)
           {
               int j = [[appDelegate.tagArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
                //mShouldBufferUpdate = TRUE;
               [self getSetSongData:j :x];
               [audioPlayer2 play];

           }
    }
   }
    if(appDelegate.xCordTrack3Array!=NULL && [appDelegate.track3tagArray count]>0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<[appDelegate.xCordTrack3Array count];i++)
        {
            if (i ==  0)
            {

                if (sfxCount3-1 !=  [appDelegate.xCordTrack3Array count])
                {
                        if ([appDelegate.xCordTrack3Array count] > [appDelegate.mMixedSFXTrack3Array count] )
                        {
                            mShouldBuffer3Update = TRUE;
                            sfxCount3 = [appDelegate.xCordTrack3Array count];
                        }
                    }
                }

            if (x==[[appDelegate.xCordTrack3Array objectAtIndex:i] intValue] && appDelegate.imgDragXCodr1<480)
            {
                int j = [[appDelegate.track3tagArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
                [self getSetSongData:j :x];
                [trac3AudioPlayer play]; //For SFX Sounds

            }
        }
    }

if (x == 480)
{
    x=20;
}
}
}
```

When i click on scrollView it generates an image in UIView(main View) at that time NSTimer is getting paused.

How can we solve this.
Any one can help or suggest me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201425/running-nstimer-on-a-thread

Comment: Finally i found because of for loops which are present in singleTapGestureCaptured:(1 for) and in updateplayer(2 for) the pausing the timer how can we resolve this

Comment: Don't timers only fire when the runloop is running? You could try manually running the runloop inside your for loops.